# How to apply custom theme from Theme Builder to standalone SAPUI5 app in index.html?

Tags: sapui5, s4hana, ui5-tooling

I made a custom SAPUI5 theme through transaction `/UI5/THEME_DESIGNER` in S/4HANA on premise and successfully applied it to my Fiori launchpad.

Can I somehow reuse it in my standalone SAPUI5 app without adding it to the url?

What I tried so far:
In my `index.html`

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
    data-sap-ui-theme="<custom_theme>"
...
```

This successfully causes some CSS downloads in the network tab, like from

- `<hostURL>/sap/public/bc/ui5_ui5/1/resources/sap/ui/layout/themes/<custom_theme>/library.css`
  but nothing happens visually.

Only when I add

- `?sap-theme=<custom_theme>@<hostURL>/sap/public/bc/themes/~client-<client>/~cache-p`

to the url it suddenly works. This proofs to me that I just don't understand how to add the theme in my `index.html` - I tried many different approaches, like adding `data-sap-ui-theme-roots` but can't figure out what the correct syntax/path is...